# Accessing partition inside VirtualBox running Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

How to map local partition / folder / drive with assigned letter like windows. This is useful to access from virtual machine installed within Ubuntu with virtualbox.

Answer (score 4):

Accessing your folder from your host (Ubuntu) with a guest operational system should not be very difficult.

The tools are supplied by VirtualBox to allow sharing of folder without having to rely on network sharing protocols like `samba` of `nfs`.

Of course all of this depends on the host and on the guest but normally involves 3 steps:

- Install the guest additions for the guest system, [supported
  systems](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp6131888) are:
  Windows, Linux, Solaris or OS/2

[image]

- From the guest VirtualBox window go to *Devices* > *Shared Folders*
  and on the new window click on the green `+` button to add a
  folder/drive from your host to the mounting points list

[image]

- Third and last step is from within the guest system to mount the
  share you just created using the [specific
  commands](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_manual)
  inside the guest system to mount them. Ie, for windows that would be something like pressing the `Win`+`R` keys and typing `net use x: \\vboxsvr\sharename`. Your host's `sharedname` folder would then be mounted as drive letter `x:` inside your windows guest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial that shows how to share a folder:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/share-ubuntu-home-directories-using-samba/

More details on this page:

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/install.html#smbconfminimal

Comment: @Pandya, so you want to mount the native OS's (windows I'm presuming) C: drive in ubuntu? First, which version of ubuntu are you running? Second, are you trying to do this via the /etc/fstab file?